# Farm backups take a very long time

Tags: 2010

My farm backups seem to be getting longer and longer to complete. It has gone from about 3 hours to 8-9 hours in the space of month. The growth of the database in that time has been a slow steady increase and in no way validates the current backup times.

- I use SP2010
- The current farm backup is around 17GB and completes without errors
- I backup to a drive on my App server
- The back up starts after the native SQL backup and does not clash
- All my servers are virtual and there are no known problems with the SAN

Any suggestions\troubleshooting tips will be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

17GB required 8 to 9 hours that really ring a bell.

Is there any major change in the SharePoint in terms of any customization applied or large workflows created or any CU / SP applied.

Some time complex structure of site collection cause this kind of issue.

If you have AntiVirus Installed on the server then make sure scan is not running during that time frame and also follow the [MSFT guideline to skip the certain folder from SCAN](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/952167).

From Central Admin, view the job history and check which timer job running during the bakup duration.

Make sure no Search Crawl is running during backups & User Profile sync also not running.

Make sure no windows backup running during that time frame.

Check the ULS logs to see if any timeout or backup related issue.

Check the Server performance i.e CPU, Memory and Disk I/O.